# How to create a function that returns the first value of sorted list in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL function that returns the first value of a sorted list, but I really don't know how to start? The function has only one parameter which is the listing number ( `VRI.Listing_Number` )

Using `select` statement, I have:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 
        --VRI.Listing_RID, VRI.Listing_Number, VRI.Listing_Price, CH.Old_Price, CH.Date_Time_Changed
        CH.Old_Price
FROM    dbo.View_Report_Information_Tables VRI WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN dbo.MLS_Change_History CH WITH (NOLOCK) ON
            VRI.Listing_RID = CH.Listing_RID
        INNER JOIN dbo.MLS_Change_History_Type CHT WITH (NOLOCK) ON
            CH.Transaction_RID = CHT.Transaction_RID
WHERE   CHT.Change_Type_Display = 3 AND
        VRI.Listing_RID = CH.LISTING_RID
ORDER BY CH.Transaction_RID DESC
```

This sql query returns the last price changes from a list of prices.

I'm really new to sql, so I even don't understand quite well the syntax. For example, I looked up the `CH.Old_Price`, and I saw it `TYPE_NAME` is `numeric`, but it also has length and precision, scale.... What should my return value for this function?

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the problem? the syntax of the function? does this `select` statement return what you want?

Comment: @vlad: Sure, syntax, and maybe some explanation. Sorry, a person from DBA sent me this sql query and asked me to play around with it, but I'm completely new to sql function :(, so I really don't know where to start except go to stackoverflow ^_^!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FirstPriceChange(@Listing_Number int)
RETURNS MONEY
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (
    SELECT  TOP 1 
            CH.Old_Price
    FROM    dbo.View_Report_Information_Tables VRI WITH (NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN dbo.MLS_Change_History CH WITH (NOLOCK) ON
                VRI.Listing_RID = CH.Listing_RID
            INNER JOIN dbo.MLS_Change_History_Type CHT WITH (NOLOCK) ON
                CH.Transaction_RID = CHT.Transaction_RID
    WHERE   CHT.Change_Type_Display = 3 AND
            VRI.Listing_RID = CH.LISTING_RID AND
            VRI.Listing_Number = @Listing_Number
    ORDER BY CH.Transaction_RID DESC
)
END
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
SELECT
    VRI.Listing_RID, VRI.col1, VRI.Col2,
    dbo.FirstPriceChange(VRI.Listing_Number) AS FirstPriceChange
FROM dbo.View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Notes:

1. `RETURNS MONEY` it returns a money type
2. `WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` if the input is null, just return null
3. The returns is a single value, which is from the subquery, with the VRI.Listing_Number filter added

Comment: Very clear explanation. It's really helpful for a sql-noob like me. Great thanks. By the way, if `VRI.Old_Price` is numeric type, will it make any difference?

Comment: @Chan - change the return type (money) to match the column, so it would be `numeric(n,m)`

Answer (score 1):

assuming the `select` statement you posted returns the correct data, the syntax of the function is rather simple:

```
CREATE FUNCTION <Inline_Function_Name, sysname, FunctionName> 
(   
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@Listing_Number int, 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
-- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
)
```

you can also get this by right-clicking `Functions` in SSMS -> Object Explorer ->  -> Programmability and choosing the right type of function.  My sample above assumes that this returns an entire row of data (which seems to be the case). I also assumed that `VRI.Listing_Number` is an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM (

SELECT *
FROM    dbo.View_Report_Information_Tables VRI WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN dbo.MLS_Change_History CH WITH (NOLOCK) ON
            VRI.Listing_RID = CH.Listing_RID
        INNER JOIN dbo.MLS_Change_History_Type CHT WITH (NOLOCK) ON
            CH.Transaction_RID = CHT.Transaction_RID
WHERE   CHT.Change_Type_Display = 3 AND
        VRI.Listing_RID = CH.LISTING_RID
ORDER BY CH.Transaction_RID DESC

) AS `aaa`
```